# Delete rows if letters in cell SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I needed some guidance as to how I can exlude rows that contains any form of letter in a cell that is supposed to contain integers only.

This is what the data looks like now:

```
CustomerID
----------
ea176680
27906857
62675436
62566247
1bed413e
61110053
61113323
34441416
```

AS you can see in the table, the first,ID contains letters. How can I remove complete rows if a cell were to contain any form of letters?

Comment: "Remove" as in "not show in a result set" or "Remove" as in "permanently delete this row from the table"? If the latter, do you also want to prevent such data from appearing again?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever he said exclude, so I assume he means excludefrom a query.

Comment: @SQLPolice - The title of the question says "delete". And I don't like to assume. That's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this `where` clause?

```
where CustomerId not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

It filters out any values that have a non-digit.  Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't support regular expressions, but this will do what you want.

If you specifically wanted to look for letters, you can do:

```
where CustomerId like '%[a-zA-Z]%'
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server can [match on a specific pattern](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx) in your statement using `like`. It looks somewhat like regex, but isn't exactly that.

Use this statement if you want to match on all `CustomerId`s that contains characters in the range `A-Z` and `a-z`:

```
select *
from   table
where  CustomerID like '%[A-za-z]%'
```